# IIS rewriting with slug generation having issues with ampersands

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I'm attempting change a url like

example.com/company/company-1

to

example.com?slug=company-1

I re-write using the following pattern

```
<rule name="company">
    <match url="^company/([_0-9a-z-()]+)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="company.php?slug={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

in my web.config file.

This works until a company name containing an ampersand e.g. ham-&-eggs

The company name is url encoded, so it actually arrives like ham-%26-eggs

which my pattern writes to example.com?slug=ham-

I have tried adding the ampersand to the pattern

e.g.

```
<match url="^company/([_0-9a-z-()&amp;]+)" />
```

and

```
<match url="^company/([_0-9a-z-()&]+)" />
```

Both of which result in a server error.

What can I do without changing the incoming url composition?

Thanks in advance

Nick

Comment: How about putting smth simpler, e.g. "^company/([^/]+)"

Comment: yes, I just tried your suggestion, and had previously just matched anything after the ^company/ but they both throw a 500 server error

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the `UNENCODED_URL` variable, which stores the original url (not unencoded, which splits the `&` into a new parameter).

You can run matches against these conditions and use the `{C:1}` syntax instead of the `{R:1}` syntax (which matches against the encoded rule pattern) if you need to.

See: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference